# Run a program lik send keys when i am logged in to my shpping cart at amazon

Tags: python, sendkeys

I am logged into Amazon.com
Can I run a program to send keystrokes to the Website ?
I want to provide my employees with a way to make a payment from a file the program accesses.
The object is to verify the amount of the sale.
Compare ti the the amount in the Approved file.
Then tab to the profile
add my credit card as a payment method
Make sure the items are going to address in the first file.
then make the payment.
Wait for confirmation of the sale.
save the page to the first file.
restart the send keys program to go beck into the profile
and remove my credit card info.
then to log out.

Comment: its possibly but sounds like a massive security risk.

Comment: the object is to reduce the security risk.

Comment: I have 2 tables 1 with an approved payment amount for the card.

Comment: The other has the credit card ifo hidden from the operator - eventually i want to automate it and eliminate the operator.

Comment: Storing credentials in a file and passing them to a browser sounds super insecure

Comment: How is the info hidden, wouldnt it be easier to store the card on amazon its self so the card truley is hidden?

Comment: I would use something like autohotkey to automate keystrokes on the client side (windows only). Depending on how it's implemented, it would be no more or less secure than them entering credentials themselves.